# I have implemented a mini shell. Now i want to extend it to include redirection and pipes

Tags: redirect

Where exactly that code has to be integrated ? In the shell or within the commands itself or before forking ?

Comment: can you be more specific in what you want to achieve. From what I understand, the she shell you are using takes commands from user and then fork a new process to execute the given command. Now instead of displaying the output to screen(stdout), you can redirect it to a file descriptor. This is how you can use the redirection part. Now using pipe is very similar except that you need to reuse output file descriptot of onceprocess as the input of the other

Comment: I got it for the redirection by implementing it after forking .. now working on pipes.. Just a small doubt ? We have to implement redirection for ls,ps,pwd and system commands only ???  Because cd , mv ,tail ,mkdir and rm are still taking command line argument.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Implement in the shell.  It's just manipulating file descriptors, which are inherited when you fork the child processes, which are the commands.